# How to unescape with javascript and translate with Google?

Tags: javascript, html, window, google-translate

i have some code, when i input some test to text box and click Tranlate it will translate to English:

```
    <html> 
    <head> 
    <style type="text/css">
    input {font-size:12px; width:600px;}
            </style>    
    <title>Translate</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head> 
    <body> 
            <div class="translate"></p>
        <div class="translate_control" lang="en">   
        <input id="text1" class="translate"/>
         <script>
            function googleSectionalElementInit() {
            new google.translate.SectionalElement({
            sectionalNodeClassName: 'translate',
            controlNodeClassName: 'translate_control',
            background: '#f4fa58'
         }, 'google_sectional_element');
}
        </script>
        <script src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleSectionalElementInit&ug=section&hl=en"></script>   
    </body>
    </html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4CXGf/

Now, i want input some code to **text1** as: \u83B7\u53D6\u9875\u9762 and i want when i click Translate it will auto **unescape()** with javascript **"\u83B7\u53D6\u9875\u9762"** to **获取页面**  and auto translate to English with Google translate and show to **text1**. How to do it?

Sorry about my English!

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what your input is supposed to be here - could you please provide an example of what you're attempting to do?

Comment: @JoshfromQaribou: thank for reply! Example: i want input some code to text1 as: \u83B7\u53D6\u9875\u9762 and i want when i click Translate it will auto unescape() with javascript "\u83B7\u53D6\u9875\u9762" to 获取页面 and auto translate to English with Google translate and show to text1. How to do it?

Comment: Answered this question a while back. Please find it below.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a shorter way to do this, but one option is to use the JSON predefined class to handle all the escaping. encodeURI/decodeURI sound like the most obvious approach, but neither of them work in the direction you're trying for, which is to take a string literal that actually says "\u83B7\u53D6\u9875\u9762", including literal backslashes. What you want is to essentially re-evaluate the input string.

I was able to do this like so:

```
var escapedInput = document.querySelector("#text1").value;
var encodedChars = JSON.parse("\"" + escapedInput + "\"");
```

Now my `encodedChars` are `获取页面`. Pass that to your translate.

Comment: thank you very much for help but i don't know to use JSON :( i will learn more about JSON.

Comment: You don't have to know anything about JSON. Just copy and paste my code and get your encoded version out of encodedChars. I'm simply using JSON as a means of unencoding.

Comment: I don't want to come off as rude, but it sounds like you have a lot more learning to do before you're ready to do work as a programmer. The snippet should be more than adequate for solving your problem -- nobody is going to do the implementation for you.

Comment: Thank you for help, i will learn more to solve my problem. Sorry about my English!